# Watch DVR content online?

Tags: home-networking, dvr

I would like to be able to watch DVR content online and one of the things I'm considering is converting a my HOME PC into a Linux DVR.  I have very little (almost none) experience with Linux and before I begin this effort, I wanted to make sure I was on the right track...

1. The only product that exists in the market today to watch home DVR content from TIVO or cable boxes is Slingbox.
2. You can simply share the files that are created onto the home DVR online and access them through SSH, FTP, or some other connectivity...
3. A Linux box would be best for this use case...

My primary goal here is having a DVR at home that will allow me to watch the content wherever I am.  For example, if I were to travel to Europe, I could connect to my home's DVR to watch content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend a [Slingbox](http://www.slingbox.com), quite frankly, it is achievable what you want to do, but I can just imagine you spending hours upon hours with no result and a [Slingbox](http://www.slingbox.com) would work perfectly.

You may be able to use something like [Geexbox](http://geexbox.org/en/index.html) or [Mythbuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/) with remote access, but in my experience, it just gets real messy really fast and just not as good as a [Slingbox](http://www.slingbox.com) which would work well.